# How can I identify which button was clicked using MVVM Pattern in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am using MVVM Pattern. I have two buttons. on Click I need to identify which button was clicked. How I can bind buttons in XAMl so that I can identify which button was clicked.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please share your code here.

Answer (score 1):

If you really use MVVM then bind `Command` of each button to corresponding `ICommand` in your view-model. It will be two different commands so you don't need to do any special actions to distinguish one button from another.

XAML:

```
<Button Content="FirstButton"
        Command="{Binding Path=FirstCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>
<Button Content="SecondButton"
        Command="{Binding Path=SecondCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

View-Model:

```
public sealed class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
    public ICommand FirstCommand { get; }
    public ICommand SecondCommand { get; }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same `Command` for multiple buttons, you can use `CommandParameter`.

```
<Button Content="buttonContent1" Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"                    
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"/>
```

And in your command delegate method you can use something like this:

```
private void ButtonClickCommandHandler(object parameter)
{
    switch(parameter.ToString())
    {
        case buttonContent1:
        ...
        case buttonContent2:
        ...
    }
```

}

Here button is identified by its content of course you can change it to some other property like `Tag`

Comment: Both `Content` and `Tag` properties is a very bad choice for the `CommandParameter`. It will be much better to create enum where each field will identify a button, and pass those fields as `CommandParameter`.